# C++ error reading character of string

Tags: c++

I am trying to add an array to my Object which contains dynamic array

MyCollection.h

```
    template <typename T>
    MyCollection<T>::MyCollection(int size)
    {
        arraySize = size;
        anArray = new T[size];
    }

    template <typename T>
    MyCollection<T>::MyCollection(MyCollection<T>& coll)
    {
        arraySize = coll.arraySize;
        anArray = new T[arraySize];

        for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
        {
            SetValue(coll.GetValue(i), i);
        }
    }

    template <typename T>
    MyCollection<T>::MyCollection(T* myArray, int size)
    {
        anArray = myArray;
        arraySize = size;
    }




   template<typename T>
    void MyCollection<T>::AddAll(T pArray[], int size)
    {
        int plusSize = size - 1;
        int arrayIterator = 0;
        arraySize += size;


        for (int i = size; i < arraySize - plusSize; i++)
        {
            anArray[i] = pArray[arrayIterator];
            arrayIterator++;
        }

    }
```

Main

```
MyCollection<string> B = MyCollection<string>(new string[3], 3);
    B.SetValue("C", 0);
    B.SetValue("D", 1);
    B.SetValue("E", 2);

string C[3];
    C[0] = "X";
    C[1] = "Y";
    C[2] = "Z";

B.AddAll(C, 3);
    B.Display();
```

In the AddAll method I have error with acces violation. When I add watch anArray[i] = . Is there any idea why that happens? Is it problem with copy construcotr or so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `AddAll()`, you need to resize the raw array `anArray`, there is no resizing going on (you just change the numeric value of `arraySize`, but do not allocate more memory). So you need something like

```
delete[] anArray; 
// ...
anArray = new T[arraySize];
```

You may also think whether you want to copy the old elements into the newly allocated array, in which case you first have to reallocate with a temporary pointer, then copy into it, then delete the original `anArray`, and finally assign the temporary pointer to the original `anArray`, something like:

```
// save the old size
int oldSize = arraySize;
arraySize += size;
T* tmp = new T[arraySize];
// copy from anArray into tmp, use oldSize
// for(...){...}
delete[] anArray;
anArray = tmp;
```

Comment: So now If i do it like anArray = new int[newsize] then I will delete elements or not ?

Comment: @miechooy You need first to explicitly delete the memory pointed by the old array, then reallocate. If you don't delete, you end up with a memory leak. See the updated edit.

Comment: T* tempArray[] = new T[arraySize];

 for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
 {
  tempArray[i] = anArray[i];
 }   Cannot convert string to *string

Comment: @miechooy you need to save the old size, so you don't copy using the new size. Also, `T* tempArray` instead of `T* tempArray[]`.

Comment: @miechooy Also, think about adding one member function that does *only* resizing, call it `resize()`. Then implementing `AddAll` will be a breeze, you just invoke `resize()` then add the new elements at the end. Functions should be small and should do in general only one task, and do it well.